# ListView animation. Only 1 of 2 animations working

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a `ListView` in which when I click on a row item header, it expands (with animation) and shows some more info below it. When clicking the row item header again, it is supposed to play another animation which shrinks it.

The expanding animation is working fine, but the shrink animation is not working at all.

**Why is only the `expandDownAnim` working and not the `shrinkUpAnim`?**

**ListView Row XML**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/horizontal_line" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/schedule_header_bg"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <com.walintukai.lfdate.widgets.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_blue" />

    <com.walintukai.lfdate.widgets.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/is_active"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_radius" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/horizontal_line" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <com.walintukai.lfdate.widgets.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="@string/start" />

            <com.walintukai.lfdate.widgets.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/start_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <com.walintukai.lfdate.widgets.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="@string/end" />

            <com.walintukai.lfdate.widgets.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/end_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rangebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:tickHeight="0dp"
        custom:tickCount="24" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**BaseAdapter which has the animations (shortened)**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_schedule, null);
        holder.header = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        holder.day = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
        holder.isActive = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.is_active);
        holder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        holder.rangeBar = (RangeBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rangebar);
        holder.tvStartTime = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start_time);
        holder.tvEndTime = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end_time);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (mSchedules.get(position).getDate() != null && !mSchedules.get(position).getDate().isEmpty())
        holder.day.setText(getFormattedDate(mSchedules.get(position).getDate()));

    if (mSchedules.get(position).getIsActive()) {
        holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_on);
        holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_green_radius);
        holder.container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_off);
        holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_radius);
        holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSchedules.get(position).getIsActive()) {
                mSchedules.get(position).setIsActive(false);

                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.shrink_up);
                anim.setDuration(300);

                holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.container.setAnimation(anim);
                holder.container.animate();
                anim.start();

                holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_off);
                holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_radius);
            }
            else {
                mSchedules.get(position).setIsActive(true);

                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.expand_down);
                anim.setDuration(300);

                holder.container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.container.setAnimation(anim);
                holder.container.animate();
                anim.start();

                holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_on);
                holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_green_radius);
            }
        }
    });

    final DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");

    int startTime = mSchedules.get(position).getStartTime();
    int endTime = mSchedules.get(position).getEndTime();

    LocalTime localStartTime = new LocalTime(startTime, 0, 0);
    LocalTime localEndTime = new LocalTime(endTime, 0, 0);

    holder.tvStartTime.setText(timeFormatter.print(localStartTime));
    holder.tvEndTime.setText(timeFormatter.print(localEndTime));
    holder.rangeBar.setThumbIndices(startTime, endTime);

    holder.rangeBar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIndexChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftThumbIndex, int rightThumbIndex) {
            mSchedules.get(position).setStartTime(leftThumbIndex);
            mSchedules.get(position).setEndTime(rightThumbIndex);

            LocalTime localStartTime = new LocalTime(leftThumbIndex, 0, 0);
            LocalTime localEndTime = new LocalTime(rightThumbIndex, 0, 0);

            holder.tvStartTime.setText(timeFormatter.print(localStartTime));
            holder.tvEndTime.setText(timeFormatter.print(localEndTime));
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

**UPDATE 1: added AnimationListener**

Added an `AnimationListener` to my animation, but now when I click to close a row, it gets stuck and only will close if I click another row that is currently closed. Then all the rows that were supposed to close would all close at the same time (triggered by the click of the row that is currently closed).

```
holder.header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSchedules.get(position).getIsActive()) {
                mSchedules.get(position).setIsActive(false);

                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.shrink_up);
                anim.setDuration(300);
                anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }
                });

                holder.container.setAnimation(anim);
                holder.container.animate();
                anim.start();

                holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_off);
                holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_radius);
            }
            else {
                mSchedules.get(position).setIsActive(true);

                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.expand_down);
                anim.setDuration(300);

                holder.container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.container.setAnimation(anim);
                holder.container.animate();
                anim.start();

                holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_on);
                holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_green_radius);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

because you set the **visibility** to **GONE** before starting the animation.
you have to change:

```
            holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.container.setAnimation(shrinkUpAnim);
            holder.container.animate();
            shrinkUpAnim.start();
```

and set the visibility to GONE **onAnimationEnd()**, this is an example:

```
yourAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: I applied the code, but now when I click the row header (which toggles the container open/closed) it just sticks there. The only way it closes up again is if I click another row's header which is currently closed. Then the container closes for the previous one. Does that make sense? I am assuming this has something to do with the recycling views.

Comment: please update the question with you new adapter code (to know what you have changed)

Comment: add convertView = null; before if (convertView == null){} to test if the problem is caused by the recycling!

Comment: Same thing happens if I set convertView to null. But I tested by opening all the rows, and if I close one, and scroll off screen then back to that one, it ends up closed.